# vNext MVC Template - wwwroot

Tags: asp.net-core

I created vNext MVC Template then created a folder named images under wwwroot. I call like this:

```
<img src="~/wwwroot/images/album/1.jpg" />
```

But, the image is not loading. How can I reach that image?

Comment: Solved: <img src="~/images/album/1.jpg" />

remove: wwwroot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting this as an answer with more details so that others will see.

The `wwwroot` folder in the app is the root of the static, servable files. As such, `wwwroot` does not appear in the URLs. Take a look at the `project.json` file to see where that comes into play:

```
{
    ...
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    ...
}
```

This is telling ASP.NET vNext that static files (the "webroot") are located in the `wwwroot` sub-directory. This is the default location where the Static File middleware will return files from.